# install VLC on ubuntu 64bit -- 15-05-15 (closed)

Tags: vlc

i use ubuntu software center to install VLC but it's error :

```
vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.2-2) but 2.1.2-2 is to be installed

Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 is to be installed

Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.4 is to be installed

Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed

Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed

Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu22 is to be installed

Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed

Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

Could you help me please, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the other libraries on which VLC installation depends. You can either do

```
sudo apt-get update
```

`sudo apt-get upgrade -y`

`sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc`

```
sudo apt-get -f install #if you have already tried to install the package and get the missing dependent libraries error.
```

Alternatively you can download the package from **Ubuntu Software Center** or the [VLC website](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) itself. Download the deb package and install with

```
sudo dpkg -i install package name
```

Comment: You can also sudo dpkg --configure -a to reconfigure things.   And then sudo apt-get autoremove to maybe delete hanging packages.